# How to set a buttons width dynamically to match its title value in Titanium?

Tags: ios, uibutton, titanium, appcelerator

Creating a button in Titanium it gets a 100% width from the system if width is not defined or 
set to auto:

```
var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Some Title',
    width: 'auto'
});
```

I want to have the button have the exact width of its content without calculating the contents width myself or setting it manually.

In the documentation I can not find any options to achieve that.

Is there an option to have the button width match its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to allow me to close it:

Currently a default button can not be sized dynamically to its content in Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

Favo, I'm not sure I understand the question. I believe the answer to your question is setting the width to auto, so why is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: auto is not matching the button's width to its content, auto sets the button width to 100% width of its parent container :(

Comment: Ahh, I see.  It might be easier to do with a label instead. It's essentially the same type of element.